# Django Models custom methods

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

is there any way to call a specific model custom method from a view? i need to subtract or increment  depending on the view  a field on my model, I want to create a button for each of the two options and after imputing that data update the field in my database. if so how can i go about  implementing it, currently my save method is doing the two operations at once

models.py

```
class Items(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey('Categorias', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    c_actual = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    c_descuento = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    c_incremento = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrito = models.ForeignKey('Carrito', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
    p_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True )
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, null=True, blank=True)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.c_actual = self.c_actual - self.c_descuento
        self.c_actual =self.c_actual + self.c_incremento 
        self.total = self.c_actual * self.p_unitario
        super(Items, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.nombre, str(self.categoria), str(self.c_actual), str(self.total))
```

Comment: Well why does your `.save(..)` function does that? It can only introduce problems, race conditions, etc.? Furthermore here your `.total` gets overridden each time. You *model* should not handle this, but the *view*(s) should.

Comment: @Willem. Initially i wanted only to add a amount to that field and calculate the total. now i want to be able to ad or subtract , and i dont know how to implement it. my intention is to have two methods one for adding and one for subtracting but i don't know how to make the view just call that method or if its possible ... frankly  in relatively new to programing

Comment: But that makes no sense. A model is not meant to *do* something in a very strict sense. It is meant to *store* a thing, to add and guard certain constraints, and to define functions on these models. The views are supposed to "do things".

Comment: I guess i misunderstood "slim views, fat models" that I've seen on some tutorials. can custom methods be run on class based views to?

Comment: but even fat models do not do that. A model guarantees invariants, and it provides functionality to move in the state space. But the views pull the triggers. A model does not update itself automatically...

Comment: Alright. so I guess I can make my  updateview  get the value an increment  or decrement the field . but how would i go about getting the total when the item is initially created? could that be done trough the save method on the model?

Comment: well if `total` is always equal to `c_actual * p_unitario` I would not make it a field, since that creates *data duplication*, which is an anti-pattern. In that case it is better a `@property`, or `.annotate(..)`tion.

Comment: Got It! I'll look it up and try to implement it . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an instance method on the model e.g. exactly like the `get_absolute_url()`.

You can add 3 methods in the model definition increment, decrement and total and write the respective logic in there.

So the view in the views.py file be something like

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    #read the post data values from req

    #create model instance
    data = Items( #key value pairs)

    #read from req to increment or decrement
    if incr: 
        data.increment()
    else: 
        data.decrement()
    
    data.total() 

    data.save()

    return render( ... )
```